# Adding c++ OpenBLAS library to c# project

Tags: c#, c++, dll, import, blas

I'm trying to use OpenBLAS in a c# project (more specifically I'm attempting to use it with Math.NET via `MathNet.Numerics.Control.LinearAlgebraProvider`).  I've successfully created the files following https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS/wiki/How-to-use-OpenBLAS-in-Microsoft-Visual-Studio.

Now I have a .lib and .dll file in a new directory (as per subsection **Use OpenBLAS .dll library in Visual Studio**), but I'm not sure where to go from here!

Does anyone know what I'm supposed to do from here? I cannot directly add the generated dll to my project, and from further reading it seems like I need to generate a new dll using Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Use the NativeWrappers solution file provided by MathNet.

Similar instructions for MKL and ACML are here: 
http://mathnetnumerics.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Native%20Providers&referringTitle=Documentation